What is the Shape Formed by a Rubber Band Tracing Ellipses with a Moving Focus?

Hi,
I'm experimenting with a rubber band and I'm curious about the maximum area it can cover without stretching. I believe this involves tracing a series of ellipses with one focus fixed and the other focus moving along a line. Specifically, I'm considering changing the focus of an ellipse while keeping the semi-major axis constant.
From my animations, I ended up with a lens-like shape. Is there a specific name or mathematical description for this shape?

The term-of-art for the shape surrounding such a family of curves is an envelope. The envelope of your family of ellipses happens to be the overlap of two parabolas. Can you verify this yourself? (Briefly: write the Cartesian equation of the family parameterized by $c$ as $F(x,y,c)=0$, and then use the equation $\partial F/\partial c=0$ to eliminate $c$.)

There is a simple geometric way to construct the envelope of your ellipses. Consider an ellipse with foci $O$ and $A$ (blue in figure below) and another one with foci $O$ and $A'$, with $A'$ very close to $A$ (red in figure below).
Let those two ellipses intersect at some point $B$: as the length of the major axis is fixed, we have: $OB+AB=OB+A'B=2a$, that is: $AB=A'B$. Hence point $B$ lies on the perpendicular bisector of $AA'$.

In the limit $A'\to A$, that perpendicular bisector becomes the perpendicular at $A$ to line $OA$ (which is fixed) and $AB$ becomes a semi-latum rectum of the ellipse with foci $O$ and $A$, as in figure below.
This limiting position of $B$ belongs by definition to the envelope of the ellipses, which is then the locus of point $B$ as point $A$ varies.
It is well known that the semi-latus rectum of an ellipse with semi-major axis $a$ and semi-minor axis $b$ is $b^2/a$.
If we set $OA=x$ we get then:
$$
y=AB={b^2\over a}={a^2-(x/2)^2\over a}=a-{x^2\over 4a},
$$
which is the equation of the locus of $B$ (a green parabola in figure below) if we take $O$ as origin and line $OA$ as $x$-axis.
Note that this parabola is tangent to all the ellipses.

We didn't consider the second point of intersection, which gives another parabola, reflection of the first one about $x$-axis. The envelope is formed by the arcs of both parabolas, delimited by the intersection points of the parabolas with $x$-axis.
The area of the envelope can then be computed via Archimedes' theorem, as we have two parabolic segments with base $2a$ and height $a$:
$$
area=2\cdot{4\over3}\cdot2a\cdot a={16\over3}a^2
$$

In 2D that shape is a symmetrical lens.  In 3D, that shape is a lemon, which is a circular segment (or symmetrical lens) revolved around its chord connecting the endpoints of the arc(s).

That particular curve may be a parabola or catenary rather than a circular arc.
